# JAVA string to HTML size

Tags: java, html

I have simple string that i am write into `Report` that write into `HTML` file:

```
Report.Write("my text");
```

Is it possible to send `string` with other size and other color ?

This is what i have try and the result was bold string:

```
"<p>my text</p>"
```

Comment: Java to HTML???? Do you know what you are asking? Because either JSP or Javascript would more likely be the language.

Comment: I mean to wrap the text with HTML elements to change this text style when i see it on the HTML file

Comment: Can you provide your html? I don't quite understand what it is you want.

Comment: Do you want to use Javascript?

Comment: I don't know because i don't have this report code so if it is possible i want they both to see what's works

Comment: So you do not know what programming language you want to use?

Comment: I have this report that i am writing into and i need to write several strings, all i want is to check if is it possible to enlarge the size and change color.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: All i have to do in order to report is this: Report.Write("my text"); can i have an example how to do that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93415/discussion-between-mark-yer-and-adam-buchanan-smith).

Answer (score 0):

A String only contains characters; it cannot contain text size or color data. You may want to consider something like this:

```
String text;
String color;
int size;
// some code to initialize these variables

private static void writeHTML(BufferedWriter Report, String text, String color, int size) {
    String HTMLText = "<font size=" + size + " color=" + color + ">" + text + "</font>";
    Report.Write(HTMLText);
}
```